# How I run z3 solver on python

Tags: z3, z3py

Hi I am new on z3 prover, I try to learn this solver but I cant figure out how I run on python.
I try to run these codes on python:

```
    (declare-const A Int)
    (declare-const B Int)
    (declare-const C Int)
    (assert (and
    (= A 98798798987987987987987923423)
    (= B 763429999988888888887364578645)
    (= (+ (* 87 A) (* 93 B)) (+ C C))))
    (check-sat)
    (get-model)
```

my file name is "ex" and I call "z3 -smt2 ex" but it gives error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
Also I dont understand how I download z3 tools from this website(https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki)Thank you!

not: I use Visual Studio Code as a compiler

Answer (score 1):

Note that the example you posted is in SMTLib format; i.e., it's not a python program that uses z3py. And `z3 -smt2 ex` should work just fine on it, since z3 can read SMTLib natively. Since you're getting an error message, your build is most likely busted for some reason. You should follow the download/install instructions in https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/README.md, essentially:

```
python scripts/mk_make.py -x
cd build
nmake
```

and report if any of the steps listed there isn't working for you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I run mk_make.py  and I write  pip install z3-solver into command line in Visual Stuido Code however I cant understand "cd build" and "nmake" . What I need to do for this step?   I recall again z3 -smt2 ex and gives same error

Comment: Switch to the build directory, and type `nmake`. Perhaps you need help from someone else around you, if these instructions don’t work for some reason, as it doesn’t get any more basic than that.

Comment: I typed before "cd build" and "nmake" into the command line but it gave error The term 'nmake' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program...

Comment: You need to install `nmake` first. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=msvc-170 Since you have visual-studio, see if you can install it's command line tools. See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview

Comment: actually I try to run code starts with "from z3 import *........." but it gives error "bad magic number in 'z3': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'". I try to solve this issue ( My main aim is solving  N-Queens problem with Z3.) Thanks!

Comment: Your installation seems terribly busted. This is no longer really a z3 issue. I recommend get help from microsoft/windows/visual-studio installation tags.

Comment: Thank you. I will do it, last question how I compile  this codes: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/0vercl0k/z3-playground/master/nqueens_z3.py I need to install z3 solver to run in python . Thanks

Comment: Once python and z3 are both installed in your system, simply run `python file.py`, where you put the content of that link into a file named `file.py`.

Comment: Note that you don't really need to build z3 unless you really want the latest code from GitHub master. You can simply install an existing package using `pip install z3-solver`. (This may be a bit old, but might just do the trick for you.)